# cbind column in several csv files in r

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, cbind

I am new to R and dont know exactly how to do for loops.
Here is my problem: I have about 160 csv files in a folder, each with a specific name. In each file, there is a pattern:"HL.X.Y.Z.", where X="Region", Y="cluster", and Z="point". What i need to do is read all these csv files, extract strings from the names, create a column with the strings for each csv file, and bind all these csv files in a single data frame.
Here is some code of what i am trying to do:

```
setwd("C:/Users/worddirect")
files.names<-list.files(getwd(),pattern="*.csv")
files.names 
head(files.names)
>[1] "HL.1.1.1.2F31CA.150722.csv"  "HL.1.1.2.2F316A.150722.csv" 
 [3] "HL.1.1.3.2F3274.150722.csv"  "HL.1.1.4.2F3438.csv"        
 [5] "HL.1.10.1.3062CD.150722.csv" "HL.1.10.2.2F343D.150722.csv"
```

Doing like this to read all files works just fine:

```
files.names
    for (i in 1:length(files.names)) {
    assign(files.names[i], read.csv(files.names[i],skip=18))
            }
```

Adding an extra column for an individual csv files like this works fine:

```
test<-cbind("Region"=rep(substring(files.names[1],4,4),times=nrow(HL.1.1.1.2F31CA.150722.csv)),
        "Cluster"=rep(substring(files.names[1],6,6),times=nrow(HL.1.1.1.2F31CA.150722.csv)),
        "Point"=rep(substring(files.names[1],8,8),times=nrow(HL.1.1.1.2F31CA.150722.csv)),
        HL.1.1.1.2F31CA.150722.csv)
 head(test)
  Region Cluster Point          Date.Time Unit  Value
1      1       1     1 6/2/14 11:00:01 PM    C 24.111
2      1       1     1  6/3/14 1:30:01 AM    C 21.610
3      1       1     1  6/3/14 4:00:01 AM    C 20.609
```

However, a for loop of the above doesn`t work.

```
files.names
    for (i in 1:length(files.names)) {
    assign(files.names[i], read.csv(files.names[i],skip=18))
    cbind("Region"=rep(substring(files.names[i],4,4),times=nrow(i)),
        "Cluster"=rep(substring(files.names[i],6,6),times=nrow(i)),
        "Point"=rep(substring(files.names[i],8,8),times=nrow(i)),
        i)
            }
>Error in rep(substring(files.names[i], 4, 4), times = nrow(i)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument
```

The final step would be to bind all the csv files in a single data frame.

I appreciate any suggestion. If there is any simpler way to do what i did i appreciate too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve a problem in R. A more R-like way to solve this problem is with an `apply()` function. The `apply()` family of functions acts like an implied for loop, applying one or more operations to each item in passed to it via a function argument.

Another important feature of R is the anonymous function. Combining `lapply()` with an anonymous function we can solve your multi file read problem.

```
setwd("C:/Users/worddirect")
files.names<-list.files(getwd(),pattern="*.csv")
# read csv files and return them as items in a list()
theList <- lapply(files.names,function(x){
     theData <- read.csv(x,skip=18)
     # bind the region, cluster, and point data and return
     cbind(
          "Region"=rep(substring(x,4,4),times=nrow(theData)),
          "Cluster"=rep(substring(x,6,6),times=nrow(theData)),
          "Point"=rep(substring(x,8,8),times=nrow(theData)),
          theData)
})
# rbind the data frames in theList into a single data frame  
theResult <- do.call(rbind,theList)
```

regards,

Len

Comment: dude, you are a magician! Worked perfectly. So, in this case, why does "read.csv(x)" works? i thought i would had to do a `for` loop to read each csv and to add the other columns

Comment: Hello @CaesarGan. I explain the details of this technique in my article [Forms of the Extract Operator - Assignment 1 Concepts](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md#concepts-for-r-programming----programming-assignment-1), which I wrote to support the Johns Hopkins Data Science Specialization *R Programming* course.  Also, please accept/upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is number, which doesn't have nrow property.

You can use following code

```
result = data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(files.names)) {
    assign(files.names[i], read.csv(files.names[i],skip=18))
    result = rbind(
                  cbind(
                      "Region"=rep(substring(files.names[i],4,4),times=nrow(files.names[i])),
                      "Cluster"=rep(substring(files.names[i],6,6),times=nrow(files.names[i])),
                      "Point"=rep(substring(files.names[i],8,8),times=nrow(files.names[i])),
                      files.names[i]))
}
```

Comment: Kppatel Patel, interesting, thank you . Unfortunately, in this case, i am still getting the same error: "Error in rep(substring(files.names[i], 4, 4), times = nrow(i)) :   invalid 'times' argument"
i am still not entirely sure how to get the number of rows of each csv file using this loop (each csv has a different nrows)

Comment: Are you using Rstudio or R, If you are using Rstudio, then you can use break inside loop and see what happens during breakpoint. Or You can use just basic print statement.

Comment: Hum, didnt know that. Awesome. I appreciate the tip!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `files.names[i]` evaluates to a text string, so `nrow(files.names[i])` returns `NULL`, which is invalid for the `times` argument. To make this logic work, you'd need to use `nrow(get(files.names[i]))` to retrieve the data frame. `get()` is the complement of `assign()`.